# How can I make a list group (bootstrap) only take up a small amount of space but still stay center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a set of list groups separated by a date. I'm  trying to center the list groups so I can start selling banner ads because I'm not eligible for AdSense. I can make it smaller, but then the list isn't centered. Thanks for your help!

The code comes from the following JavaScript:

```
function getSongList(xml) {
  var x, i, xmlDoc, txt, j;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  txt = "";
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DAY");



  for(j = 0; j<=x.length; j++){
    txt = "";
    z = x[j].getElementsByTagName("SONGNAME");
    y = x[j].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST");
    w = x[j].getElementsByTagName("DATE");
    p = x[j].getElementsByTagName("LINK");

    var date = document.createElement('h1');
    date.className = 'date'
    var date_id = 'date' + j
    date.id = date_id;
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.appendChild(date);
    var date_data = w[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById(date_id).innerHTML = date_data;


    for (i = 0; i< z.length; i++) {
      txt += "<a href=" +  p[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      txt += "class='list-group-item'>";
      txt += "<b>";
      txt += z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      txt += "</b>";
      txt += " - ";
      txt += y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      txt += "</a>";

    }

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'list-group';

    var div_id = 'list' + j;
    div.id = div_id
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.appendChild(div);


    document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = txt;
  }

}
```

It uses the bootstrap element list-group.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please put the problem code in your question instead of linking to a site.

Comment: okay i changed it